# How can I get DevExpress "Rename a variable" to work in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress, coderush, refactorpro

How can I get DevExpress "Rename a variable" to work in VS 2008?

I just upgraded from VS 2005 to VS 2008. In VS 2005, the F2 key used to invoke the DevExpress Rename. In VS 2008, F2 appears to do nothing.

I installed both DevExpress CodeRush and RefactorVB. I am not sure if RefactorVB was what I had installed on VS 2005. We stored all the DevExpress programs to install in a directory. Besides RefactorVB.NET-3.2.3.exe there is also Refactor!Pro-3.0.5.exe.

Should I be using Refactor!Pro-3.0.5.exe?

**Updated:**

After downgrading to Refactor!Pro-3.0.5.exe and also CodeRushNET-3.0.5.exe the F2 started working. I then noticed **Rory** answer but I was not able to test it out because I already did the downgrade. As a learning experience, I followed Rory's steps and the F2 is assigned to Rename in the downgraded version. I must say, DevExpress has one pretty feature packed Option dialog box.

Comment: If you have any other Coderush/Refactor based questions, feel free to find me on twitter @roryBecker or email me direct (roryBecker [a t] gmail [d o t] com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the shortcut has become disabled. this is the default in recent versions of this software.

Try the Following:

1. **Open Options Screen** 
    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> launches the options screen.
2. **Locate the Correct Options page** 
    Locate the `IDE\Shortcuts` folder on the leftmost edge of the options screen
3. **Locate the Correct Shortcut/Folder**
   The `Refactor\Alternate Bindings` folder contains the shortcut you are looking for.
4. **Reenable the shortcut**
   Either the `Alternate Bindings` folder or the **<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut** within it may be disabled. This should be a checkbox with the phrase Enabled next to it in either case. Ensure both are enabled, and then hit ok
5. **You're done**
   Things should now work as you expect.

**What should you be using?**

If you have indeed upgraded to VS2005 , then you should use Coderush Xpress version 9.2.6 (The latest version at the time of posting) available from http://www.devexpress.com/crx

DevExpress chose to combine all the products you mentioned previously into this single install/product. It is still entirely free, but will only work with VS2008 Pro or better.

Alternatively you might consider their paid version http://www.devexpress.com/Coderush

I have a comparision of them [here on my blog](http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2009/07/coderush-vs-coderush-xpress.html).

Comment: OMG.  I consider myself quite proficient at searching forums/boards/google/etc and I've been looking for this answer for 30 minutes.  I think what threw me for a loop in the CodeRush Options Screen > IDE > Shortcuts,  was not having the "Refactor!" folder expand on single-click.  Thanks!  I finally have my F2 Rename :)